# Add and remove cells based on values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Original Post: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778826/copy-cells-based-on-format-and-values) (New post as it started to get very clunky and dragged away from the issues at hand)

I am looking to automatically grab data from an excel CRM output and take certain values into a new sheet. I have had a bit of luck with my progress, but I am still struggling to adapt the code properly.

First Iteration of Code:

```
Sub Client_CRM()
   
    Range("A4:A44,C4:C44,G4:H44").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output Sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Current code:

```
Sub Client_CRM()

Dim ClientStartRow As Long, ClientEndRow As Long
Dim Listed As Long
Set PortfolioRange = Worksheets("Client Paste").Range("A:M")
Set Listed = Worksheets("Client Paste").Range("A:A")

With Sheets("Client Paste")

Sheets("Output Sheet").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Client Paste").Activate

ClientStartRow = .Range("A3").Row
':A").Find(What:="Listed", after:=.Range("A1")).Row
ClientEndRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="Totals", after:=.Range("A3"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Row

Range(ClientStartRow & ":" & ClientEndRow).Select
Selection.Columns(1).Copy
Sheets("Output Sheet").Select
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B1:B70") = Application.VLookup(Listed, PortfolioRange, 8, False)
Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("C1:C70") = Application.VLookup(Listed, PortfolioRange, 3, False)
Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("D1:D70") = Application.VLookup(Listed, PortfolioRange, 7, False)

    End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, I've slowly added and learnt more things throughout today.

What I am now looking to do is:

- Find a better way to copy the columns over to the new sheet. **An issue that I have encountered is that maybe 1/10 CRM exports have an additional column, so the VLOOKUP can't accurately be used 100% - The CRM export has headers. Can I use some sort of code to grab these columns by value? They are exported and on Row 2. "Listed" "Quantity" "MV" "PW" are the 4 headings. Usually they are columns: 1,3,7,8 but in a rare instance they are 1,3,8,9...
- Find a way to remove certain "blacklist" products. All products generally have a 3 part code that they are identified as. There are certain 3 part codes I do not want included and I want to be able to update this as time goes on. Ideally, I'd like to make a separate sheet with these codes and if they match to anything from the export, they aren't copied over...
- Some product codes have 5 characters instead of 3, I'd like these ones to be coped in the same list but added to a separate list (Unsure if this is possible?)

**Update:**

Have worked out how to get the code to bring the 4 columns I want regardless of their order over.

```
Set PPSExport = Range("A2:M2")

For Each cell In PPSExport

If cell.Value = "Asset" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("A:A")
    
    
End If

If cell.Value = "Quantity" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("B:B")
End If

If cell.Value = "Market value" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("C:C")
End If

If cell.Value = "Portfolio weight %" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Output Sheet").Range("D:D")
End If


Next cell
Sheets("Output Sheet").Select


    End With
```

Thanks for any help,

I've already learnt so much already -- any pointers would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of these things are possible.  I will give a brief description on how to accomplish all of these things, but I recommend that you try to research how to do each of these tasks on your own before asking another question(s).  It's also a good idea to keep the scope of your question limited.  For example, you are asking about 3 loosely related items here.  Yes, they are related to one another via your project, but in the general world of VBA programming, they are not.  This will keep the conversation focused and easier to follow.

> Find a better way to copy the columns over to the new sheet.

You made a great observation: your data is imported with headers.  And your proposal is possible.  You can certainly use the headers of a range (or table) to copy data.  You could:

1. Iterate through all cells in the header row
2. If you come across one you are interested it, copy all of the data in that column to the new sheet
3. If you come across a column header you are not interested in, just skip it and move to the next one

> Find a way to remove certain "blacklist" products.

This is possible, and your proposed solution sounds ideal to me.  Keep a record of all blacklist values in a sheet, and reference that list when necessary.

> Some product codes have 5 characters instead of 3, I'd like these ones
> to be coped in the same list but added to a separate list

Certainly possible.  Once you have your data:

1. Iterate through all of it and check how many characters are in the value
2. If there are 5, copy that data to a new location or store it somewhere
3. If there are not 5, move on to the next value

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will try and work out some solutions today. It's getting past the point of my knowledge but haha, might need to do some bedtime reading to figure the next part out